# C splitting character array read from a file by \n (newline character), strange output

Tags: c, arrays

I am reading a raw text file into a character array and then I want to split the data line by line based on "\n". My code is attached, but I get very strange output.

INPUT FILE is a .txt file created with VIM on Windows, and it looks like:

```
london
manchester
britain
...
```

CODE (ignoring some var declarations):

```
....
char * buffer = 0;
long length;
fl = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
if (fl){
  fseek (fl, 0, SEEK_END);
  length = ftell (fl);
  fseek (fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
  buffer = malloc (length);
  if (buffer){
    fread (buffer, 1, length, fl); 
  }
  fclose (fl);
  printf(buffer)
}else{
  printf("data file not found");
  return -1;
}

char str[80] = "london\nmanchester\nbritain";
char* entity = strtok(buffer, "\n");  //LINE-A, replacing 'buffer' with 'str' the output is correct.
while (entity != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", entity);  //this prints strange output as shown below
  entity = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```

....

OUTPUT:

```
ondon
anchester
ritain
```

The first character is always missing.

However, if I replace "buffer" with "str" the declared character array with the same content as the file everything works as expected.

I do not understand why I am getting this error. Any advice please.

Mnay thanks!

Comment: Check buffer in a Debugger or hex dump it's content to be sure it is really equal to str.

Comment: copy paste of the program and your three lines of input as posted, adding the includes it prints correctly - maybe also could use `:set list` to show hidden characters in vim

Comment: No problem with the code, See http://codepad.org/tFoGEaUC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the fact that you aren't terminating your string buffer. I'm unable to produce your exact problem but I do get unexpected extra characters in the output. Amend the relevant lines of your code as follows and see if that helps:

```
buffer = malloc(length + 1);
if (buffer) {
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, fl);
    buffer[length] = '\0';
}
fclose(fl);
```

---

If that doesn't solve your problem, you might have some weird (invisible) control characters in your text file. Try creating a brand new one and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Thanks all. I tried a new file from scratch (both code and input data file), and the problem is gone. This is really strange. Previously the code I posted is part of a larger file. I suspect if it messes with other lines of code causing the problem... for now it seems to be working. But I have a new problem related to this and I am posting a new question.